# bluetoothd error: adapter_ops_setup failed

Tags: bluetooth, raspberry-pi, bluetooth-lowenergy, bluez, gatt

I am trying to create a GATT Service with BLE in Raspberry pi 2 (*Kernel Version: Linux raspberrypi 4.1.7-v7+ and Bluez version: 5.11*). I have connected leoxsys BLE adapter with the pi. I am able to advertise as iBeacon and the advertising signal is detected in "Beacon Bits" iOS App. Based on [this tutorial](http://gaiger-programming.blogspot.in/2015/01/bluetooth-low-energy-customizing-gatt.htm) I ran the command  `sudo /usr/sbin/bluetoothd --plugin=time -n` to start the example GATT service. It returned the following:

```
bluetoothd[4818]: Bluetooth daemon 4.99
bluetoothd[4818]: Starting SDP server
bluetoothd[4818]: Ignoring (cli) pnat
bluetoothd[4818]: Ignoring (cli) audio
bluetoothd[4818]: Ignoring (cli) sap
bluetoothd[4818]: Ignoring (cli) input
bluetoothd[4818]: Ignoring (cli) serial
bluetoothd[4818]: Ignoring (cli) network
bluetoothd[4818]: Ignoring (cli) proximity
bluetoothd[4818]: Ignoring (cli) service
bluetoothd[4818]: Ignoring (cli) gatt_example
bluetoothd[4818]: Ignoring (cli) alert
bluetoothd[4818]: Ignoring (cli) health
bluetoothd[4818]: Ignoring (cli) thermometer
bluetoothd[4818]: Ignoring (cli) hciops
bluetoothd[4818]: Ignoring (cli) mgmtops
bluetoothd[4818]: Ignoring (cli) formfactor
bluetoothd[4818]: Ignoring (cli) storage
bluetoothd[4818]: Ignoring (cli) adaptername
bluetoothd[4818]: Ignoring (cli) wiimote
bluetoothd[4818]: Ignoring (cli) dbusoob
bluetoothd[4818]: Failed to init time plugin
bluetoothd[4818]: adapter_ops_setup failed
```

How to resolve the following error:

```
bluetoothd[4818]: Failed to init time plugin
bluetoothd[4818]: adapter_ops_setup failed
```

Comment: Per [this forum post](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=174003); what do you get when you `lsmod | grep blue`

Comment: When I ran, I got this:
`bluetooth         327544  26  bnep,btbcm,btusb,rfcomm,btintel`
`rfkill                 16659  3 cfg80211,bluetooth`